# Ajax Request not processing POST Variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have read every post and have tried everything I can for the last few hours - so I have turned to the community for help!

I have a BMI calculator, which works fine. But I am trying to process the form through AJAX, now my ajax request works fine and I am recieving a response, but it does not contain any of my POST data.

Also let me mention that I am working with WordPress.

Here is my AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
     # BMI Calculator Ajax Call
     --------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('form#bmi-calculator').on( 'submit', function(e) {

        // ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                'action' : 'fitnessgym_bmi_calculator',
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                $('.bmi-results').append( response );
                console.log( response );
            },
            alert : function( error ) {
                alert( 'error' )
            }

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

And here is my callback function:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------
  Process the BMI Calculator
--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fitnessgym_bmi_calculator', 'fitnessgym_bmi_calculator' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fitnessgym_bmi_calculator', 'fitnessgym_bmi_calculator' );


function fitnessgym_bmi_calculator() {

    // Sanitize post variables.
    $allowed_html = array();
    $weight = trim(sanitize_text_field(wp_kses($_POST['bmi_weight'], $allowed_html)));
    $height = trim(sanitize_text_field(wp_kses($_POST['bmi_height'], $allowed_html)));
    $age = trim(sanitize_text_field(wp_kses($_POST['bmi_age'], $allowed_html)));

    // Do the Calculation.
    $equation = $weight / $height;

    echo 'Weight is: ' . $weight . '<br>';
    echo 'Height is: ' . $height . '<br>';


    // If BMI is Healthy or Not.
    if ($equation < 18.5) {
        $health = esc_html__('Underweight', 'fitnessgym');
    } elseif ($equation > 18.5 && $equation < 24.9) {
        $health = esc_html__('Healthy', 'fitnessgym');
    } elseif ($equation > 25 && $equation < 29.9) {
        $health = esc_html__('Overweight', 'fitnessgym');
    } elseif ($equation > 30) {
        $health = esc_html__('Obese', 'fitnessgym');
    }

    $bmi_response = 'Your BMI is:' . number_format(esc_html($equation), 1) . '<br>Your health is: ' . $health;

    echo $bmi_response;

    wp_die();

}
```

Basically, when I submit the form what returns is:

```
Weight is: 
Height is: 
Your BMI is:
Your health is: Underweight
```

So without any of the POST information. Also let me mention that I have tried the POST variables without any sanitizing (encase anyone recommends that)  :)

I can not figure out for the life of me, why this will not display. Any help is appreciated, thank-you.

Comment: I have a feeling everyone on your current function is going to be underweight.. Use something like firebug or something else, so you can see what's being send to your ajax script..

Comment: Does your function get called anywhere in your script? You can't call them directly from the AJAX call. You need to define an url that you request and that url needs to use your function.

Comment: Your data field in ajax needs to include the post data which is missing.

Comment: I am using wp_localize_script which passes in admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) which is the URL where all WordPress ajax requests must be sent. My callback function is "fitnessgym_bmi_calculator" which processes everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not sending the data you are expecting on the backend.

Look again at your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : {
        'action': 'fitnessgym_bmi_calculator',
    },
    ...
});
```

Add the data you are expecting to get is

```
{
    'action': 'fitnessgym_bmi_calculator',
    'bmi_weight': 0,
    'bmi_height': 0.
    'bmi_age': 0
}
```

Add those missing key-value pairs to `data` and everything should work.

Comment: Thank-you for your help, that pretty much sums it up. When I am passing values into the action, the calculator is working. So that answers my question :) The other thing I am wondering now is how to pass through my POST variables to my JS file, wp_localize_script won't allow me to pass through POST variables - do you have a suggestion of how I should do this? Thanks!

Comment: I got it! You put me on the right track, thanks heaps! I passed in "'bmi_weight' : $('#bmi-calculator #bmi_weight').val()," to get the POST values in there, calculator is working schweet!